# Does lexeme and stem mean the same?

Tags: terminology, lexemes, stems

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexeme) following about lexeme:

> A lexeme is a unit of **lexical meaning**... For example, in English, run, runs, ran and running are forms of the same lexeme, which can be represented as

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_stem) following about stem:

> In linguistics, a stem is a part of a word responsible for its **lexical meaning**.

Am unable to understand whether both terms mean the same.

Comment: A stem is a lexeme always. A lexeme is not a stem by itself, it can be a stem in various ways, when appearing as part of various words.

Answer (score 12):

A "lexeme" is a theoretical thing, a unit in the mental lexicon. You can think of it as being an entire dictionary entry, but in our mental knowledge bank of what words mean rather than a physical book.

A "stem" is a practical thing: it's the part of a word that you stick affixes onto. The stem of *play*, *playing*, *plays*, *played*, etc is *play-*. In English the stem usually looks like an actual word, but it doesn't have to be: in Latin, the root of the Latin words *amīcus*, *amīcī*, *amīcum*, *amīcō*, etc is *amīc-*, which isn't a valid Latin word on its own. So you'll sometimes find the word "lemma" used to mean "the stem, with some default affix attached to make it a real word" (in Latin, that would be *amīcus*).

The concept of a lexeme is pretty standard across languages. No matter what language you speak, you have *some* sort of mental understanding of what words mean. But the concept of a stem is very useful in some languages and nigh useless in others. It all depends how much the language uses affixes.

Comment: Would it be fair to say that a stem is a *kind* of lexeme, and that "runs" could be decomposed into two simpler lexemes, the stem "run" and the suffix "-s"?

Comment: @chepner No, "runs" could be decomposed into two *morphemes*, the stem "run" and the suffix "-s".

Comment: OK, I think I'm not seeing the distinction between lexeme and morpheme. (Or is a lexeme a complete "word"?)

Comment: Would the example of [Semitic roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semitic_root) would be a useful illustration of some of these concepts?

Comment: @chepner A *lexeme* has many inflected forms: e.g. run, running, runs. These are all forms of the same word that change to fit into the sentence grammatically.

Comment: _Stem_ comes from a `Plant` metaphor theme, familiar to I-E and Semitic languages, where there is a short, often monosyllabic, chunk of language that encapsulates the basic sense, which is the **root**. Using the root, one produces different forms with same or similar meanings - each of which is larger than the root - that are called **stems**. For instance, Latin verbs have infinitive stems, perfect stems, and participial stems, each of which is further inflected. Hebrew has triconsonantal roots, each of which can be modified in many ways to produce stems.

Answer (score 4):

From the computational linguistics point of view, *and especially targeting moderately inflected languages*, a lexeme can be thought as a set of all inflected forms of a word. Such a set - a lexeme  - can be represented by something uniquely describing it, which is usually *a lemma*, a basic form of the word (this is quite language dependent). The stem can be thought as a "poor man's lemma", a part of the word that remains unchanged (there are exceptions, though - e.g. if the root morpheme mutates predictably in some cases, stemming can "undo" this mutation) and in some circumstances it could be used to represent a lexeme (but usually isn't).

Stemming is usually performed by a relatively simple algorithm without deeper linguistic consideration (such as meaning, homonymy etc.) and used for full text searches and such.

So, in English (a bad language to base an example on), a set {run, ran, running, runs}, usually with a connection to its meaning, and/or part of speech (thus depending on your level of abstraction, "run" as a noun can be a different lexeme {run, runs}) is a lexeme. A natural way of representing the lexeme is the lemma "run"; your stemming algorithm will likely give you the "run" stem as well, but it might fail for the "ran" word form.

Answer (score 3):

Lexemes and stems are not related.

A *lexeme* is an abstract concept that represents the core meaning shared by a set of closely-related *word-forms* (e.g. the concept of 'live' is the lexeme for the word-forms 'lives', 'live', and 'lived').

Lexemes are abstract concepts without phonological forms; so the word 'live' is not a lexeme, but the abstract concept of 'live' is. To make this distinction, lexemes are typically represented by writing its lemma (i.e. dictionary or citation form) in [small caps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps), like this: ʟɪᴠᴇ.

A *stem* is the part of a word that *affixes* attaches to. For example, in the word 'readable', 'read' is the stem and '-able' is the suffix. In the word 'readability', 'readable' is the stem and '-ity' is the suffix.

Comment: Clarity makes my day. :)